# In ADAM, if admin sets pwdLastSet = 0 , why response control is NULL inspite of bind throws NamingException?

Tags: ldap, adam, reset-password

I am setting pwdLastSet = 0 for user in ADAM. So while bind operation, I am getting following Exception which is correct as I am resetting password of that user by setting pwdLastSet = 0

`javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C090311, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 20ee, vece`

But after this when I tried to getResponseControl(), it is returning me NULL.
What is the reason ? I am expecting that it should return **PasswordExpirationControl**.

Can anybody help out how to resolve this ?

Comment: What query did you use? Is the user in the ADAM instance or in the AD Instance? Some more details are needed.

Comment: @jeemster : I set pwdLastSet = 0 using modifyAttributes() call of JNDI library. The user is in ADAM instance only. What more details do you need ?

Comment: Is the PasswordExpirationControl defined int he rootDSE?

Comment: @jeemster: Nope. PasswordExpirationControl is not defined in the rootDSE. In absence of the same, what error should i get while bind operation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume an error as you did receive.

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C090311, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 20ee, vece
```

This message occurs only when one of the following scenarios is true:

- The account password is expired.
- The account is locked out.
- The account password must be changed.

There was also a ADAM  1.1 with Service Pack 1 [specific bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/919336), but from what you have provided, I do not think it applies.
-jim